# Django, how to get a user by id, using the django.contrib.auth.models.User

Tags: python, django, django-models

I cant'figure it out how to get a User, from the django model, django.contrib.auth.models.User, by id... I want to delete a user so I'm trying to find it like that:

```
 User.objects.get(id=request.POST['id'])
```

But it doesn work, and returns

```
User matching query does not exist.
```

the id is sent by ajax:

```
 $("#dynamic-table").on('click','.member_delete_btn', function() {
        if (confirm("Are you sure? the member will be deleted...") == true) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/panel/member/delete/",
                data: { id: $(this).attr('data-id'), 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}' },
                success: function (data) {
                     if(data.success) {
                         $('#result').html('<div class="alert alert-success"> <strong>Well done!</strong> Member deleted.</div>');
                         list_members();
                     }else{
                         $('#result').html('<div class="alert alert-warning"> <strong>Warning!</strong> Member not deleted.</div>');
                     }
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("failure:" + data.error);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

I debug it and it's ok, the user exists in the DB and the id is correct

How do I do that? 
Is there any delete method for django User instances?

thanks

Comment: How do you populate the POST dictionary ?

Comment: like that  <a data-id="{{ m.user.id }}" href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs member_delete_btn"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Delete</a>, the data-id is passing by ajax and it's ok, I get it by print it and it's correct

Comment: Is it a plain click of the link, or is it an AJAX post ? Also, please edit the question - it is more readable that way.

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at the [django delete view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#deleteview). You can ignore the post dictionary this way by making it a part of the route.

Comment: Ok, then you might have already deleted the object ?? All the error is saying is, the object with the id you are looking for is not present.

Comment: Thanks, bu the obj still there, with the same id... I'm using the Django 1.7.2

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That is the way to do it, the problem here, is that your requested user does not exist. If you want to handle this case, use this:

```
try:
   user_id = int(request.POST['id'])
   user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
except  User.DoesNotExist:
   //handle the case when the user does not exist.
```

Also, you need transform your id to `Int`.

Comment: here is the post: <QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'zRmCkdwrEI6Lk4BgHXfxtd7aYROimsft'], u'id': [u'23']}> , the id exists in the DB yet....

Comment: @tubadc you need convert your id to int. I updated my answer.